# App stops printing until I clears Cache Data in Android

Tags: android, caching, printing

I am developing a POS application. In this app, when I print receipts from printer paired to my tablet, it prints well. But after printing some receipts, printer stop printing until I clears **Cache Data** in Tablet's Settings.

Then it starts printing again. This problem occurs whenever, Cache data size reaches 40KB only.The printer which I am using is **Star Printer**.